# Regular expression: find a substring inside a pair of tags, however there may be multiple tag pairs on a line and other text

Tags: regex

I'm struggling writing a regular expression that finds a substring `searchText` inside a pair of tags.
The complication is that the text to be searched should be inside one pair of tags, while on a line multiple pairs of the tags do exist. Even more complicated is the fact that the search text is also found between the end tag of the first tag pair and the second.
Only that occurrence of the `searchText` may be found that is inside a single pair of tags.

Example text

```
<tag> some text without search text inside</tag> more text searchText more text <tag>some text with searchText inside it</tag>
```

I want to capture only the `searchText` inside the last tag pair.

The regular expression I came up with is: `\<tag\>.+?(searchText).+?\<\/tag\>`
Of course the problem is that it searches beyond a tag pair.

**Question**: what would be a correct regular expression to only find the `searchText` in the second tag pair?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/494134

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yXwtgO/1